# Storage chest space in diablo 3 Ultimate Evil Edition is shared? Can i increase its space?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I was playing yesterday and decided to drop some gems to free my inventory. But then i saw that the chest only has 20 slots.

This chest is shared between my characters? If i change between my Demon Hunter and my Barbarian, can i see the gems? Or each character has its own separate storage chest? Can i increase its space? Or can i increase my inventory (character's) space, with some items or equipment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stash space is shared between all your characters. Hardcore and softcore is separated.

You can upgrade the stash space with pushing the right analog stick in the stash menu.
The stash can be upgraded for a total of 210 slots. (This might cost about 1M gold)

Answer (score 2):

Your chest (or stash, as it is called by the game) is indeed shared by characters of the same type (either Normal, or Hardcore). So is your gold, which you don't need to manually deposit / withdraw.

You can increase the available stash size by pressing Y on Xbox (or I assume Triangle on Playstation) when looking at the stash -- this costs gold, and gets progressively more expensive as you get more slots.